# Regex: creating a dictionary from a list of strings

Tags: python, regex, string, list, dictionary

I have a large list of strings and I would like to create a dictionary out of this.

Every different word is a key and the value is the number of times the word is present in the whole list of various strings.

I am new to Python still and am bit lost. I am sure I have to do the loop, in which I would have to:

1. Check if the next word is not a duplicate
2. maintain iterator to calculate the number of times each word exists in a dictionary

What if I use set() first to get all unique words and than loop through them and count the frequency?

Would be greatly appreciative of any advice

```
 [u'retw', u'folivi_jochan', u':', u'rt', u'newsycombinator', u':', u'uber',  u'is', u'taking', u'millions', u'of', u'manhattan', u'rides', u'away', u'from',  u'taxis', u'http', u':', u'//t.co/zluyq3f6cc'] [u'retw', u'chr1sa', u':', u'rt',  u'newsycombinator', u':', u'uber', u'is', u'taking', u'millions', u'of',  u'manhattan', u'rides', u'away', u'from', u'taxis', u'http', u':',  u'//t.co/zluyq3f6cc'] [u'retw', u'olutosinfashusi', u':', u'rt', u'newsycombinator', u':', u'uber', u'is', u'taking', u'millions', u'of', u'manhattan', u'rides', u'away', u'from', u'taxis', u'http', u':', u'//t.co/zluyq3f6cc'] [u'retw', u'shakycode', u':', u'rt', u'newsycombinator', u':', u'uber', u'is', u'taking', u'millions', u'of', u'manhattan', u'rides', u'away', u'from', u'taxis', u'http', u':', u'//t.co/zluyq3f6cc'] [u'an', u'interesting', u'read', u'manhattan', u'is', u'the', u'best', u'tv', u'show', u'that', u'hardly', u'anybody', u'is', u'watching', u'http', u':', u'//t.co/psfmauuwfg'] [u'tmr', u'am', u':', u'lunch', u'at', u'the', u'arts', u'!', u'from', u'11-2pm', u'at', u'1935', u'manhattan', u'beach', u'blvd', u'in', u'redondo', u'beach', u'!', u'map', u':', u'http', u':', u'//t.co/x6x2eeijbh'] [u's1', u'was', u'superb', u'.', u'``', u'manhattan', u'is', u'the', u'best', u'tv', u'show', u'that', u'hardly', u'anybody', u'is', u'watching', u"''", u'http', u':', u'//t.co/q6iazmtaam'] [u'taylor', u'swift', u'seen', u'leaving', u'msr', u'studios', u'in', u'manhattan', u'on', u'october', u'07', u',', u'2015', u'in', u'new', u'york', u',', u'new', u'york', u'.', u'http', u':', u'//t.co/3cwxrapr38'] [u'viva', u'a1054665', u'manhattan', u'acc', u'estimated', u'to', u'be', u'7', u'yrs', u'old', u'american', u'staff', u'mix', u',', u'white', u'/', u'brown', u',', u'spayed', u'female', u'...', u'http', u':', u'//t.co/sloopljyxq'] [u'#', u'3d', u'taevision', u"'showroom", u'in', u'the', u'night', u'#', u'porsche', u'996', u"'", u'#', u'automotive', u'#', u'fashion', u'#', u'makeup', u'#', u'ny', u'#', u'nyc', u'#', u'manhattan', u'http', u':', u'//t.co/eftvytqedk']
```

Thank you

Comment: check out https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: can you put each list in a separate line so it is more readable. You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For python 2.7 and above use `Counter` from the `collections` [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = [u'retw', u'folivi_jochan', u':', u'rt', u'newsycombinator', u':', u'uber', u'is', u'taking', u'millions', u'of', u'manhattan', u'rides', u'away', u'from', u'taxis', u'http', u':', u'//t.co/zluyq3f6cc', u'retw', u'chr1sa', u':', u'rt', u'newsycombinator', u':', u'uber', u'is', u'taking', u'millions', u'of', u'manhattan', u'rides', u'away', u'from', u'taxis', u'http', u':', u'//t.co/zluyq3f6cc', u'retw', u'olutosinfashusi', u':', u'rt', u'newsycombinator', u':', u'uber', u'is', u'taking', u'millions', u'of']
c = Counter(mylist)
print dict(c)
[(u':', 8),
 (u'rt', 3), 
 (u'uber', 3), 
 (u'newsycombinator', 3), 
 (u'of', 3), 
 (u'is', 3), 
 (u'retw', 3), 
 (u'taking', 3), 
 (u'millions', 3), 
 (u'from', 2), 
 (u'//t.co/zluyq3f6cc', 2), 
 (u'manhattan', 2), 
 (u'away', 2),
 (u'http', 2),
 (u'taxis', 2), 
 (u'rides', 2),
 (u'olutosinfashusi', 1),
 (u'chr1sa', 1), 
 (u'folivi_jochan', 1)]
```

If you have three separate lists try using `chain` from `itertools`:

```
one,two,three = [u'retw', u'folivi_jochan', u':', u'rt', u'newsycombinator', u':', u'uber',   u'is', u'taking', u'millions', u'of', u'manhattan', u'rides', u'away', u'from', u'taxis', u'http', u':', u'//t.co/zluyq3f6cc'],[u'retw', u'chr1sa', u':', u'rt', u'newsycombinator', u':', u'uber', u'is', u'taking', u'millions', u'of', u'manhattan', u'rides', u'away', u'from', u'taxis', u'http', u':', u'//t.co/zluyq3f6cc'], [u'retw', u'olutosinfashusi', u':', u'rt', u'newsycombinator', u':', u'uber', u'is', u'taking', u'millions', u'of']
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
c=Counter(chain(one,two,three))
```

`Counter` is a high performance class for counting occurences of elements in iteratables. Its most_common() method returns a list of `tuple`s `(element,count)`.
This list of tuples can be used to construct a `dict`

Comment: This will get me the most common element. I need a complete dictionary where the Key = a unique word from the list of strings, Value = word's frequency in the list of strings

Comment: Awesome!  For some rewason on the same set I am getting:     {'!': 2, ' ': 209, '#': 8, '"': 6, "'": 418, '-': 1  Can not see the error, which, I am sure I made somewhere. This is such a GREAT solution! Thanks!

Comment: Good answer. But what's the point of `most_common()`? `Counter` is already a subclass of `dict`. There's not much need to convert to `dict` at all; and if you want to you can do it directly: `d = dict(c)`.

Comment: @SebastianWozny - still can not replicate for some reason. Tried everything I can think of. Including chaining my 9 lists. Not a very practical approach!

Comment: Can you edit your first post to show your input data exactly? it looks like you have no lists, but just a huge string and it counts the occurrences of the individual letters. maybe you're missing a .split(" ")?

Comment: I wonder if you can use c.update(onelistatatime) instead of fussing with chain.  Where c is your counter instance.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach, using your `for` loop:

```
for word in strings:
if word not in dict.keys():
    dict[word]=1
else:
    dict[word] += 1
```

Above assumes that `string` is your list of words that you want to iterate.

Comment: No need for `.keys()`. Just check for membership directly against the dict.